# Anyone able to make numtel:pg package working with Meteor 1.8?

Tags: meteor

I've been using numtel:pg package for several projects in Meteor. Since Meteor version 1.8 the package isn't working correctly anymore. Anyone can point me to a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The package **seems to be abandoned**, since there is no update in 4 years(**!**).

Trying to fix a package that is this outdated is usually not worth the effort. Your best options in this case are

- Find an [alternative package for postgreSQL integration](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=postgre)
- Find a fork of the package, that has fixed the compatibility issues
- Fork the package yourself and update the NPM versions or transform the package to run without hard wiring to a specific NPM version.

**Resources to achieve that:**

https://guide.meteor.com/writing-atmosphere-packages.html#peer-npm-dependencies

https://github.com/tmeasday/check-npm-versions

**General Readings:**

https://guide.meteor.com/atmosphere-vs-npm.html

https://guide.meteor.com/writing-atmosphere-packages.html

What to do if none of this applies to you, because

- The alternatives require a lot of refactoring or even changes in the app architecture
- There is no fork that keeps the package maintained
- You are not skilled enough to fork and update the package yourself

First you should definitely open an issue on the repo and describe your problem as detailed as possible:

- Meteor version, postgre version
- Meteor version, postgre version where everything worked
- What errors do you exactly get? Best is adding a stacktrace, if possible.
- If the "error" is rather undesired behavior (not reacting, things disappear etc.) you need a very detailed description of what you did, what you expected, what (not) happened
- Add screenshots if possible
- Create a **minimal** repository that reproduces the error/issue and upload it to github; link it to your issue description

If the repo owner does not respond after a week you may trigger her attention by using `@nameOfOwner` in the comments.

By doing all these efforts you raise the chance of some community members to pick up your error (because there is less effort to reproduce when the error is documented well) and fix the issue or fork the repo.

Last but not least the **golden way** would be to deal with the issue, read about the package and how it works, check the code and try to fix it. Write some tests, document the fix and finally open a pull request in order to share the improvements with all the other package users.

Comment: I agree, in general, with you. But... the packages in atmosphere are too much "mongo-like", so I should update a huge amount of Meteor.methods to get sources work the right way... With https://github.com/meteor-stream/meteor-postgres/wiki/Getting-Started, for example, once I modify a table on db_server I have to modify it also in the meteor client and server... with https://atmospherejs.com/austinrivas/postgresql solution, instead, I have to write a notify trigger and the connected function in Meteor server... I don't think is ideal to maintain. The fork solution, is above my actual skill.

Comment: Did my answer bring you any further?